# Have elements in a for loop uniquely iterate over different anchors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, strapi

I'm trying to implement a blog into my Vue project.

```
<li v-for='blog in blogs' :key="blog.id">
     <a>{{ blog.name }}</a>
</li>
```

I'd like to figure out a way to add a unique anchor (to that blog's page) attached to each element being iterated over in the current for loop.

At first I tried simply adding another `v-for` to `<a>` that would iterate over links, however it turns out to render `blog.name` by the multiple of each arrays elements.

Doing this in the a way with loops would hopefully prevent me from typing it like this:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com"><li>{{ blogs[0].name }}</li></a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com"><li>{{ blogs[1].name }}</li></a>
<a href="https://www.etc.com"><li>{{ blogs[2].name }}</li></a>
```

Comment: the 2nd argument to the `in` is the index: `v-for="(blog, index) in blogs"`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I don't *think* so. I'm simply trying to add a unique `href` which will direct to that blog's page for each element in the loop.

Comment: After playing around with it for a bit, this seems to be what I needed. I use the second argument in `v-for` and then my anchor looks like `a :href="links[index]"> {{ blog.name }} </a>`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need properly formed data in your component's data/props.

Maybe something like this:

```
blogs: [
  { name: '...', url: '...' },
  { name: '...', url: '...' }
]
```

And then you simply iterate by v-for

```
<li v-for='blog in blogs' :key="blog.name">
     <a :href="blog.url">{{ blog.name }}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Yes I think this would work. The only issue is that my `blogs: []` is populated from Strapi, so it is empty in the actual code. I didn't think it was relevant so I didn't add it, but it looks like [this](https://gyazo.com/0dc7dd7e3bc6fbba0c945e06241809c4). Sorry for potentially text, can't preview.

Comment: Oh, okay. It is better to tune your backend because it is golden rule to prepare data as possible on backend. Vue is thin client here. :)